# JQuery script twice running in twig

Tags: jquery, twig, block, template-engine

I use `twig` for my templates. when I load `jquery` script in `{% js_block %}` it will be loading twice and i don't know why? But when i move my script out of `{% js_block %}` it's work right.  what is the problem?

```
{% extends 'layout/base.html.twig' %}
{% block js_block %}
<script>alert('Hi')</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Solution: I find the problem.  I was loaded `{% js_block %}` into `{% body_block %}`:

```
{% extends 'layout/base.html.twig' %}
{% block body_block %}
//HTML CODES
{% block js_block %}
<script>alert('Hi')</script>
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

The solution is:

```
{% extends 'layout/base.html.twig' %}
{% block body_block %}
//HTML CODES
{% endblock %}
{% block js_block %}
<script>alert('Hi')</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So what is the issue with this? Is it not sending your mail? You aren't checking your `$mail->send()` which could've thrown an error - `if(!$mail->send()){  echo $mail->ErrorInfo; }`

Comment: It's most likely that your script is being run twice. Add some logging so you can see what it's doing.

Comment: @Darren I've looked at the results, but still email will be sent twice.

Comment: @ahmed @jilykate @Darren By using `$(".person-reset-pass").unbind('click');` solved my problem. But don't trigger click event somewhere. I just use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you call the script by ajax or inside a callback function.
Run the script so the 'click' function run once, not more.
Each time you use the click function on the same element, it repeats the event listener.
**I advice you to select using "ID" instead of "class".**

Comment: By using $(".person-reset-pass").unbind('click'); solved my problem. But don't trigger click event somewhere. I just use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you trigger this 'click' event somewhere.

Comment: By using $(".person-reset-pass").unbind('click'); solved my problem. But don't trigger click event somewhere. I just use bootstrap.